# Run time memory allocation without an OS

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Recently, I have been thinking about how compile time memory allocation is accomplished. To my knowledge, the compiler allocates a fixed amount of bytes for a variable during compile-time. This makes sense for a statement like this:

```
char buffer[256];
```

The compiler would allocate 256 bytes of memory for the variable, and that would be the end of it. If I wanted to dynamically create memory, I would need to use functions like malloc provided by the OS. Then I thought of this function, which wouldn't use any OS dependent features, but it would act like dynamic allocation.

```
*char malloc(size_t size) {
    char (*mem)[size];
    return mem;
}
```

The compiler can't allocate memory beforehand, as this function could be called any number of times while the program is running. How exactly would this work? How would the compiler deal with a function like this? I would assume that the OS deals with this, but this doesn't use any OS dependent features, which means it can run on hardware without an OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `*char` should be `char*` and `mem` shouldn't be a pointer::

```
char* malloc(size_t size) {
    char mem[size];
    return mem;
}
```

This allocates `size` bytes of memory as a local variable on the stack. As you know, local variables are destroyed when the function exits. It returns a pointer to the local variable and then since the function exits the local variable is destroyed. In practice, that space will be reused for the next function call's local variables.

It is likely that if you try to allocate two blocks of memory this way you will get the same address:

```
char *mem1 = malloc(10); // using your malloc
char *mem2 = malloc(10); // using your malloc
// probably mem1 and mem2 point to the same memory now
```

And it is likely that the memory will be corrupted if you call another function, because that function is allowed to use local variables too:

```
char *mem1 = malloc(10); // using your malloc
strcpy(mem1, "abcde"); // if you're lucky, strcpy won't crash...
printf("Hello world.\n");
printf("mem1 contains %s\n"); // it won't be abcde because strcpy or printf overwrote the memory
```

In short:

> How exactly would this work?

It wouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

To narrow down the term OS - when you say OS you actually mean a "desktop OS" like Windows or Unix, which doesn't only handle multi-tasking but also memory allocation, file system, drivers etc etc. But there are also RTOS that don't do anything but handling multi-tasking - they don't care about dynamic memory allocation.

Applications that don't use a "desktop OS", such as microcontroller applications, but for some confused reason want to use `malloc` anyway, set aside a fixed amount of RAM for the heap at link time. `malloc` then rules over this memory area and goes to grab memory as it pleases from there. In this case `malloc` is implemented and handled by the compiler library alone.

This illuminates how meaningless it is to use `malloc` for such applications. First of all, embedded systems don't run multiple programs and they never stop executing the program, so it never makes sense to `free()` memory - who are you freeing it for? There are no other programs to share RAM with. Your program has exclusive access to all RAM memory available.

So you have this fixed area in RAM labelled as heap and forbidden to use for anyone but `malloc`, where you could as well have stored statically allocated variables instead. It's literally a waste of space. Because no matter what, your program must be able to handle the worst case of RAM peak usage peaks. At that point you must have a certain amount of memory available no matter if stored statically, on the stack or on the heap.

This means that any such program must set aside that exact memory in advance or it will break - it will need exactly as much RAM as needed for the worst case. And since you must support this worst case, you can't really re-use that memory for other purposes in any sensible way.

As for storing temporary variables there is already the stack, which is faster and safer. So you don't need `malloc` for that.

This is the main reason why heap allocation is never used in systems without a OS - it doesn't make sense. All the time I see confused PC programmers starting up embedded systems programming and before you know it, they start using `malloc`, because they "don't know how much memory that is needed at compile time". But on an embedded system you must always know this - you need enough to handle the worst-case scenario. And so you need to set up fixed maximum limits for everything.